# Javascript update $.post to block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feed of the latest records from the database on my site. I try to make sure that when the user makes a new action, it should appear in the site block, or do an auto-update of this function every 10 seconds, for example. In JS, I use the following code:

```
function last() {
    $('#last', function (data) {
        var name = data.name;
        var img = data.img;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/history',
            type: 'POST',
            data : {
                name : name,
                img : img
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('test');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But my browser console say error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` to 57 line, 57 line it's `$.ajax({`. And at my Laravel controller i use:

`$name = Crafts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status', 1)->first();`

What am I doing wrong, where could my mistake be?

If you need more information, I am ready to provide it.

Comment: makes no sense why is there an function that makes an Ajax call in the second argument of jQuery? You want to select an element that comes from that Ajax call? You are doing it wrong if that is the case. Or are you trying to grab data from the element and make a call?

Comment: i  try to grab data from url `/history` and display this received data at `<div id"last">`